# How to allow complete WPF storyboard animation

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, storyboard

I have following animation. Top bar that is 80px high drops down by TranslateTransform when user hover over it. I tried doing it in code behind, but was able to do it only in XAML.
The problem that i have - how can i let animation complete before reverse animation triggered. For example, user hovers over top bar, it goes down, but before animation complete, cursor leaves that area and reverse animation triggered. I guess this could be done by some global variable, but i cannot make animation work in code behind.

Here is Top bar trigger.

```
 <Border DockPanel.Dock="Top" x:Name="TopBar" BorderBrush="Wheat" Panel.ZIndex="999">
            <Border.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform Y="-80"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Border.RenderTransform>
        <Border.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseEnter">
                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="OnMouseEnterTopBar_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource OnMouseEnterTopBar}"/>
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseLeave">
                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="OnMouseLeaveTopBar_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource OnMouseLeaveTopBar}"/>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Border.Triggers>
```

Storyboards:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="OnMouseEnterTopBar">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="TopBar">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="-80"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="OnMouseLeaveTopBar">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="TopBar">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="-80"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
```

This is my attempt to reproduce XAML code in code behind, but for some reason animation is too fast, regardless what value i put as duration.

```
Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
        TranslateTransform scale = new TranslateTransform(0, -80);
        TopBar.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0, 0);
        TopBar.RenderTransform = scale;


        DoubleAnimation growAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
        growAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
        growAnimation.From = 1;
        growAnimation.To = 1.8;
        growAnimation.AutoReverse = true;
        growAnimation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
        storyboard.Children.Add(growAnimation);

        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(growAnimation, new PropertyPath(TranslateTransform.YProperty));
        Storyboard.SetTarget(growAnimation, TopBar);

        storyboard.Begin();
```

Comment: When you have a DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames in XAML that animates from -80 to 0, it's unclear why you think there should be DoubleAnimation in code that animates from 1 to 1.8. It's also unclear why you think that an animation created in code would behave differently than an animation created in XAML. Try to use DoubleAnimations in XAML instead of DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames, that only set their To property, and thus make them start at the current value of the animated property, instead of a From value.

Comment: You may also simplify your XAML by removing the TransformGroup and putting the TranslateTransform directly into the Border's RenderTransform.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution to my problem.
If we remove "From" part, whenever we change action mouse enter/leave it will change direction accordingly from that exact  point without jumping to starting point specified in "From".